# filtering out spark dataframe using udf

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with two columns, `name` and `source`. All the values in the `name` column are distinct. `Source` has multiple strings separated with a comma (,).
I want to filter out all those rows where any of the strings in the `source` column contains any value from the whole `name` column.

I am using the following UDF:

```
def checkDependentKPI(df, name_list):
for row in df.collect():
    for src in row["source"].split(","):
        for name in name_list:
            if name in src:
                return row['name']
        return row['name']
```

My end goal is to put all such rows at the end of the dataframe. How can I do it?

Sample dataframe:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                name|              source|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|dev.................|prod, sum, diff.....|
|prod................|dev, diff, avg......|
|stage...............|mean, mode..........|
|balance.............|median, mean........|
|target..............|avg, diff, sum......|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `like()` to leverage the SQL like expression without any heavy `collect()` action and loop checking. Suppose you already have a list of `name`:

```
from functools import reduce

df.filter(
    reduce(lambda x, y: x|y, [func.col('source').like(f"%{pattern}%") for pattern in name])
).show(20, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf 

test_data = [('dev','prod,sum,diff')
  , ('prod','dev,diff,avg')
  , ('stage','mean,mode')
  , ('balance','median,mean')
  , ('target','avg,diff,sum')]
  
df = spark.createDataFrame(test_data, ['kpi_name','kpi_source_table'])

df = df.withColumn('kpi_source_table', psf.split('kpi_source_table', ','))
df_flat = df.agg(psf.collect_list('kpi_name').alias('flat_kpi'))

df = df.join(df_flat, how='cross')

df = df.withColumn('match', psf.array_intersect('kpi_source_table', 'flat_kpi'))
display(df.orderBy('match'))
```

Comment: *Note:* This may not perform on larger table sizes e.g. the number of distinct values in the `kpi_name` column

Comment: this looks like it will work, but the thing is, KPI name might be a substring of one the list items in source column, and it is still failing for such cases.